# asp.net IE Scroll/Click issue when using Select2 and postbacks

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, jquery-select2

i have a strange issue when using internet explorer 8+ and select2 component.
When i select a value i do a Async-postback to refresh the dropdownlists. 
After that i cannot scroll the page or click any button until i click to the background of the page or other controls.

here is the structure of the page

Javascript:

```
$(function()
{
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function (sender, args) {
        InitSelect();
    });

    InitSelect();
});
function InitSelect(){
         $('select')
               .select2() 
               .off('change')
               .change(function () { __doPostBack(this.id, "dllChanged"); });
}
```

ASP.NET

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpBase" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpSomething" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
         <ContentTemplate>
             <CustomControl:DropDownList ID="element1" runat="server" />
             <CustomControl:DropDownList ID="element2" runat="server" />
             <CustomControl:DropDownList ID="element3" runat="server" />      
         </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
     <asp:Button id="btn" runat="server" />
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

on Firefox, Chrome, Opera it works fine...

After the change event i've have tryed to set the focus to the body of the page. Now The Buttons can be clicked but the scrolling problem still exists...

Im using :

JQuery: 1.10.2
Select2: 3.4.5 
ASP.NET: 3.5

I hope you can help me... :)

Comment: Your structure is not correct. [See this...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/256253/1823841)

Comment: u are right. But i have to place the PageRequestManager either to document.ready or to the buttom of the page. Or do you mean anything else?