# Javascript not working after postback caused by dropdown

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here is my Javascript which is working initialyy and not working after a postback.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="cash"){
            $(".cash").toggle();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="cheque"){
            $(".cheque").toggle();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="dd"){
            $(".dd").toggle();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Where have you put the javascript? Are you creating the javascript dynamically and rendering it from code behind?

Comment: Javascript is in same page. am not rendering it in codebehind. i am using this to make a div visible and invisible by checkbox tick.    <div class="cash bigbox"> cash is checkbox and bigbox is css for div

Comment: Ive done this to Solve the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', (function () {
if($(this).attr("value")=="cash"){
        $(".cash").toggle();
    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="cheque"){
        $(".cheque").toggle();
    }
    if($(this).attr("value")=="dd"){
        $(".dd").toggle();
    }
});
```

or you can use change event also