# asp.net user control and updatepanel break javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following scenario.

UpdatePanel
   GridView
      EditMode  Shows UserControl with JQuery code

Inside that usercontrol I can't see the fields from JQuery.  If I remove the update panel everything works fine.  Most examples I've found don't seem to have a usercontrol inside the update panel.  I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not. I tried using the ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock but I may have had it in the wrong place.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels) worked for me, the example didn't use wildcards though, that did the trick.  Since I had the control on datarows, each one had a different ID.

```
 function BindEvents() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("[id*='txtBox']").on("mouseover",function () {
                $(this).val("DOn't leave");
                var other = 0;
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you see the fields from jQuery? What is stopping you?

Comment: I don't know, that's my question.  I figured since the JQUery was inside the usercontrol it would be ok, but the events don't seem to fire.  I'm trying to use focusin and focusout.  I don't get any debug errors either.

Comment: You mean the script tag to include the jquery library is in the user control?

Comment: Sorry, no, just the JQuery code, the script tag is in the parent file.  Is that a problem?

Comment: Dou you have `$( document ).ready()` inside the update panel? If so this won't work. If you think about it, it makes sense, `$( document ).ready()` fires when the doument is ready, it won't fire again when the update panel, err, updates.

Comment: No, I thought about putting it inside the usercontrol though.  I'm trying to write a quick example at home.

Comment: Aslo inspect the HTML rendered to the page/update panel (use dev tool in Chrome or Firebug for Firefox) and check for ID mangling if you're using ID's for your jQuery hooks.

Comment: Ok I see the same thing here, it seems to be the event binding like I've read about.  But where should I put the scriptmanager

Comment: Check if this [SO] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels) resolves your issue...

Comment: This works at home, I tried it at work, I'll have to try it again tomorrow.  The trick is to use wildcards I'll post it above.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels) worked for me, the example didn't use wildcards though, that did the trick. Since I had the control on datarows, each one had a different ID.