# Asp.net Gridview Fixed Header with Ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I found many articles on using javascript to create fixed headers in the Asp.net Gridview.  I incorporated these article's code and everything works fine, I am able to keep the headers fixed, sort, and select row and maintain the scroll position on a selected row.  The issue occurs when I put the Gridview into a Updatepanel.  I can first scroll the Gridview, but if I sort the Gridview, the header row does not stay fixed.  Does anyone have code in Asp.net/C# as an example that I could see.

In overview the code needs to have fixed headers, able to sort and maintain a scroll position on a selectedrow in an updatepanel.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: It's hard to say anything not seeing your code.

Comment: just rebind your js after partial postback.protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "mykey", "$(document).ready(function() { fixheader(); });", true);
    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels

Comment: I have added my code to the original post.  Thank you for all of the help.