# jQuery Scrollable is not firing under update panel in c# asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

```
<script src="Style/FreezeGV/ScrollableGridPlugin_ASP.NetAJAX_2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=gvWebMaster.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
            ScrollHeight: 550
            //Width: 950
            //,IsInUpdatePanel: true // This parameter must be set to true when the GridView is inside an ASP.Net AJAX UpdatePanel.
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have a gridview and placed scrollable jquery which works fine. Placed the gridview under updatepanel, so whenever selectedindexchanged happens, scrollable jquery is not working.

I have reviewed the following articles but unable to understand them. 
[Link1](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-Plugins-not-working-after-ASPNet-AJAX-UpdatePanel-Partial-PostBack-or-when-Asynchronous-request-is-over.aspx), [Link2](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-event-handler-inside-AJAX-UpdatePanel-not-working-after-Partial-PostBack-in-ASPNet.aspx) & [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/256195/jquery-document-ready-and-updatepanels). Just I have tested like this but did not work.

```
<script src="Style/FreezeGV/ScrollableGridPlugin_ASP.NetAJAX_2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=gvWebMaster.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
            ScrollHeight: 550
            //Width: 950
            //,IsInUpdatePanel: true // This parameter must be set to true when the GridView is inside an ASP.Net AJAX UpdatePanel.
        });
    });
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        $('#<%=gvWebMaster.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
            ScrollHeight: 550
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone help me out and correct me the coding.

Comment: did you get any error in console?

Comment: nothing error received

Comment: @shenbagavali  ttry to load your code like this     `$(document).ready(function () {
    function pageLoad(){
    
            $('#<%=gvWebMaster.ClientID %>').Scrollable({
                ScrollHeight: 550
                //Width: 950
                //,IsInUpdatePanel: true // This parameter must be set to true when the GridView is inside an ASP.Net AJAX UpdatePanel.
            });
    }
        });`

Comment: @Webruster no its not working

Comment: please post as update how you added it

Comment: @Webruster got the updated plugin and issue solved, thank you for your kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution from [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Maintain-DIV-scroll-position-for-Scrollable-GridView-using-jQuery-inside-ASPNet-AJAX-UpdatePanel.aspx). They have updated & released the ScrollableGridPlugin jQuery version 3.0 which solved the postback issue. Plugin is available in the above link.